# Publication at IEEE

Tags: coding-theory

Currently I am researching on coding theory, in which I focus on the repair degree/ locality. I have read quite a lot of research papers in this area. I would like to publish a paper containing an overview and works of other people, so it is like compiling those who have done something in this area. Also I intend to use this paper as a guide to those who are interested in this area but don't know how to apply coding theory in this area (like how do we relate erasure of node in netwok with error in codeword, etc).

My question: Should I submit this paper to IEEE? Because there is no new idea in the paper, it is just a compilation of existing work and some personal opinions on how to link coding theory in network coding in distributed storage system. I am feeling confused here

Comment: I am not sure whether such a paper would be acceptable as a regular IEEE "transactions" paper, unless it is for a special issue related to the topic. You may want to consider IEEE Communications Surveys & Tutorials.

Comment: Is there any platform which receives such paper?

Comment: If you are asking about the submission procedure, you will find details on the dedicated site for the journal you are interested in submitting to. I believe all IEEE journals use the manuscript central platform.

Comment: I would be a bit hesitant to accept such a survey paper, unless it brings to light new connections between the listed problem areas. For example IEEE Transactions on Information Theory has published semi-tutorial survey papers in the past, but they have the air of invited papers (haven't checked whether that was always the case), and often in special issues as pointed out by Stelios. If the reviewers like it a lot, sure. But would it necessarily get past the editor? Depends.

Comment: FWIW as a recently appointed associate editor of coding theory for the said journal I will say wishy-washy things lest I cross a line. At least until I have consulted the editor-in-chief :-)